# Reading and Validating Rows with Aspose JAva

Tags: java, cells, aspose

I am trying to read and validate a Row with Aspose Cells Java, but I have never used ir before and de documentation is not very clear, it doesn't even show you how to read a Row. Heres what I've done so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dataDir = "C:\\Users\\apoac22836\\Desktop\\";
    Workbook wb = new Workbook(dataDir + "Example.xlsm");
    Worksheet worksheet = wb.getWorksheets().get("BOM");

    int column = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

        Cell lastCell = worksheet.getCells().endCellInColumn((short) column);

        for (int row = 0; row <= lastCell.getRow(); row++) {
            Cell cell = worksheet.getCells().get(row, column);
            System.out.println(cell.getStringValue());
        }
        column += 1;

        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

I brings the value of the cells by columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need to efficiently enumerate all the data (non empty values) in a range, rows, cells, you may try to use Range.iterator(), RowCollection.iterator() and Cells.iterator() method to get the iterator for specific range, initialized rows and non empty or initialized cells, see the following sample codes for your reference:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
//Range Iterator.
Workbook book = new Workbook("sample.xlsx");
Worksheet sheet = book.getWorksheets().get(0);
Range range = sheet.getCells().getMaxDisplayRange();//You may also create your desired range (in the worksheet) using, e.g sheet.getCells().createRange("A1", "J11");
Iterator rangeIterator = range.iterator();
while(rangeIterator.hasNext())
{
Cell cell = (Cell)rangeIterator.next();
System.out.println(cell.getName() + " is not empty");
}

//Cells Iterator.
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Book1.xls"); 
Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
Cells cells = sheet.getCells();
//Get the iterator from Cells collection
Iterator cellIterator = cells.iterator();
//Traverse cells in the collection
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
      Cell cell = (Cell) cellIterator.next();
      System.out.println(cell.getName() + " " + cell.getValue());
}

//Rows collection Iterator.
String filePath = "c:\\source.xlsx";

Workbook workbook = new Workbook(filePath);

Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

RowCollection rows =  worksheet.getCells().getRows();

Object obj = rows.iterator().next();

Iterator<Row> rowIterator = worksheet.getCells().getRows().iterator();

while(rowIterator.hasNext())

{

      Row r = rowIterator.next();

      Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = r.iterator();

      while(cellIterator.hasNext())

      {

            Cell cell= cellIterator.next();
            System.out.println(cell.getStringValue());

      }

}
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

I am working as support developer/Evangelist at Aspose.